# Solutions of $\partial_t f =-\Delta^2 f$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I'm looking for references (or direct solutions :) ) of how to solve the following partial differential equation : $\partial_t f =-\Delta^2 f$ , with $\Delta f$ the Laplacian of $f$.

I'm interested in the one dimensional (1d) problem, and the 2d and 3d, and in any way to solve it, including Laplace and Fourier transform. Also, I'm interested in different geometries (1d, cartesian, radial, spherical...).
But  I'll be glad of anything you could help me with (even the name of that equation if it has one) !

Comment: It's the heat equation, but with negative diffusivity.

Comment: @rafa11111 It's not: in the heat equation, there is Laplacian. Here, we have a Laplacian square

Comment: Sorry, I see know. I did not pay enough attention.

Comment: This equation is called biharmonic heat equation.  In Fourier space, the solution (assuming enough regularity) of the initial value problem is $\hat f(t,\xi)=e^{-t|\xi|^4}\hat f_0(\xi)$. However, after the inverse Fourier transform you end up with something ugly.